# Как перехватить событие сворачивания клавиатуры в EditText?

Tags: клавиатура, события

После ввода текста в EditText нужно сделать некоторые вычисления.
Но не факт, что пользователь нажмет Enter, он же может просто свернуть клавиатуру. EditText один, фокус остается в поле, поэтому событие потери фокуса не работает.

---

Вот это помогло
https://github.com/yshrsmz/KeyboardVisibilityEvent

Comment: Сворачивание клавиатуры ещё не означает, что пользователь завершил ввод... может, она ему просто сейчас мешает - решил там посмотреть цифирь какую в другом приложении, или просто пальцем промахнулся - а ему подарочек в виде запустившейся обработки...

Comment: Подарочек в виде вывода на экран предварительного подсчета.
В моем случае не страшно.

Comment: Тогда вообще не вижу проблемы... чего ждать-то полного ввода? Делай свою процедуру расчёта такой, чтобы она могла быть прервана в любой момент, и по любому вводу в поле прерывай текущий расчёт и начинай новый, с новым аргументом - содержимым поля. А юзер пусть в процессе ввода развлекается промежуточными итогами предварительных подсчётов.

Comment: Нужно чтобы по окончании ввода, число в поле Edit привелось к маске 000.00
Если после каждого нажатия исправлять текст, курсор встает на начало строки

Comment: *Если после каждого нажатия исправлять текст, курсор встает на начало строки* А что мешает запомнить позицию курсора (и выделения, будет оно в поле есть) и восстановить после корректировки значения? обычная же практика...

Comment: Пользователь ввел 1, отобразилось 001,00 и курсор на втором знаке.
0|01.00
Как-то не то.

Comment: *Пользователь ввел 1, отобразилось 001,00 и курсор на втором знаке. 0|01.00* Почему это на втором? Если не форматировать, было бы **1|**, значит, с форматированием должно быть **001|.00**. А после ввода следующей цифры **012|.00**. А после нажатия точки **01.|00**. А после ввода следующей цифры - **012.3|0**. И так далее. Да, логика получится сложноватая - но это и есть следствие неопределённости, завершён ли ввод, если клиент свернул клавиатуру.